# Nginx regex match

Tags: regex, nginx-location

New to regex and I am trying to get my head around this problem.

The request received can contain a combination of %20 (url encoded spaces) which needs to be replaced with +

Example scenarios -

1. /path/acme%20brand/2018/shoes?__source_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.source.com
2. /path/acme%20brand/2018/mens%20formalshirts?__source_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.source.com

My code is as below

For example 1
    `path match: (.*)(%20)(.*)
    rewrite: /$1+$3`

For example 2

`path match: (.*)(%20)(.*)(%20)(.*)
  rewrite: /$1+$3+$5`

However it's not scalable to keep increasing the path match as there could be a number %20's on a URL.

Unable to use Lua programming. Please suggest a scalable way to group and replace %20 with +.